# Cómo puedo modificar el programa para que cuando el usuario ingrese la contraseña esta muestre ***** (asteriscos) en vez del texto plano? LINUX

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_INTENTOS 3 //numero de intentos
/*------------------------------------------------------*/
char pass[8];
char user[15];
short intentos = 0;
short autorizado;

void login(){
  int strcmp(const char *user, const char *pass);

  do
  {
    autorizado = 1;
    printf("**************\n");
    printf ("User: ");   scanf("%s", user);
    printf ("Pass: ");   scanf("%s", pass);
    if (strcmp(user,"root") || strcmp(pass,"root"))  //si no coinciden ...
    {
        printf ("Error\n");
        autorizado = 0;
        intentos++;
      }
      if (intentos > NUM_INTENTOS)   //si sobrepasa el numero de intentos ...
      {
        printf ("demasiados intentos\n");
        exit(1);
      }
      system("clear"); //system("clear");   //limpiamos la pantalla
    }while (!autorizado); //repetimos hasta que no esté autorizado
    printf ("LOGIN CORRECTO\n");
    //-- aquí lo que haga el codigo si coincide la clave y usuario

}
```

Comment: Usando el estándar no hay solución a tu problema, lo siento. Las soluciones son dependientes del Sistema Operativo que estés usando (o también puedes tirar de librerías de terceros)

Answer (score 4):

En Windows esto te puede funcionar:

```
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[10] = { 0 };
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10;i++) {
        s[i] = _getch(); _putch('*');
        if (s[i] == 13) break;
    };
    printf("\nYour pass is %s", s);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652182/how-to-display-asterisk-for-input-password-in-c-using-clion

En Linux o en otros sistemas operativos POSIX, no existe `getch` pero lo puedes replicar con `termios`:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int getch() {
    struct termios oldt, newt;
    int ch;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
    return ch;
}
```

No es algo muy usado, se prefiere que no se vea nada en lo absoluto, apagando los mecanismos de `echo` que devuelven e imprimen la entrada en la terminal.

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856635/hide-password-input-on-terminal